# Can I make JUnit more verbose?

Tags: java, junit

I'd like to have it yell hooray whenever an assert statement succeeds, or at the very least have it display the number of successful assert statements that were encountered.

I'm using JUnit4.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why exactly do you want that? I always try to follow the rule of silence (http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch01s06.html#id2878450), that's why I'm asking

Comment: It might be a useful way to see if someone is "tweaking" the test cases to make them pass by removing unconfortable assertions...

Comment: Because it gives me the warm fuzzies when that number legitimately goes up. :)

Comment: If you have complex, long-running tests, some indication of progress can be useful

Comment: @AllainLalonde - how did you make the output displayed on the console ? I have tried the basic examples I am not able display the output on console [here is my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928025/junit-testing-assert-output-not-being-displayed-on-console)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to see some output for each successful assertion, another simple approach which requires no external dependencies or source code, would be to define your own Assert class which delegates all methods to the standard JUnit Assert class, as well as logging successful assertions (failed assertions will be reported as usual by the JUnit class).

You then run a global search-and-replace on your test classes from "org.junit.Assert" => "com.myco.test.Assert", which should fix-up all regular and static import statements.

You could also then easily migrate your approach to the quieter-is-better-camp and change the wrapper class to just report the total # of passed assertions per test or per class, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Adding some info that would have been helpful to me when I wanted JUnit to be more verbose and stumbled on this question.  Maybe it will help other testers in the future.

If you are running JUnit from Ant, and want to see what tests are being run, you can add the following to your task:

```
<junit showoutput="true" printsummary="on" enabletestlistenerevents="true" fork="@{fork}" forkmode="once" haltonfailure="no" timeout="1800000">
```

Note that showoutput, printsummary, and enabletestlistenerevents are what helped, not the other task attributes.  If you set these, you'll get output like:

```
Running com.foo.bar.MyTest
junit.framework.TestListener: tests to run: 2
junit.framework.TestListener: startTest(myTestOne)
junit.framework.TestListener: endTest(myTestOne)
junit.framework.TestListener: startTest(myTestTwo)
junit.framework.TestListener: endTest(myTestTwo)
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.495 sec
```

This was useful to me when my tests were timing out and I wasn't sure which tests were actually taking too long, and which tests got cancelled because they were unlucky enough to be running when the time was up.

Comment: Is there anything equivalent for running tests using maven and surefire?

Answer (score 5):

You can use AOP (with Spring or AspectJ) define pointcuts on all assert methods in junit.framework.Assert class. Using spring you can implement your own class as  after returning advice (http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-advice-after-returning) which will only be called if the assert method passed (otherwise it throws an exception: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
). In you own class you can implement a simple counter and print it at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Are you really interested in an assertion that succeeds?  Normally, the only interesting assertions are ones that fail.

Being a fervent JUnit devotee myself, I try and make the output of the tests as quiet as possible because it improves the signal-to-noise ratio when something doesn't pass.  The best test run is one where everything passes and there's not a peep from stdout.

You could always work on your unit test until it succeeds and run "grep Assert test.java | wc -l".  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Hard to be done. All assert methods are static members of the class Assert, which implies that the RunNotifier (which counts the successful and failed tests) is not within reach.

If you dont refrain from an ungly hack: take the sources from JUnit, patch them to store the current notifier in a static field of Assert when running tests such that the static methods can report successful asserts to this notifier.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can create a custom TestRunner that does that. We ended up with something similar in our homemade Unit-testing framework (a clone of NUnit).

Oh, wait - now that I'm reading your question again, if you really want output for each successful assertion, you'll have to dig into the plumbing more. The TestRunner only gets called once for each testcase start/end, so it'll count passed and failed *tests*, not assertions.

This isn't much of a problem for me, since I tend towards one assertion per test, generally.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, it's the goal of JUnit to count matched assertions or print out more verbose information.
If tests are atomic, you'll get most information in there. So I would review my tests.

You're also able to establish a LogFile in JUnit. It's possible, but it will decrease test execution performance...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a straight answer to the question and is in fact a misuse of a junit feature, but if you need to debug some values that are used in the asserts, then you can add *temporarily* something like:

```java
Assume.assumeTrue(interestingData, false);
```

This won't fail the build, but will mark the test as IGNORED, *and* will force the values to be included in the test report output.

> ❗️ *Make sure to remove the statements once you are done. Or, as an alternative, you can change the statement to `Assume.assumeTrue(interestingData, true)` in case you might want to debug it again in the future.*

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked a long ago but just to add:

Isn't it  better to get the reports generated as html under the `build` folder and refresh the browser after every test?

Using Gradle (as it offers support for Junit out of the box with its plugins for integration) I'm able to open the file at `build/reports/tests/test/index.html` in my project and check the results in a per package, per class, and per method basis.

[image: Exemplo Relatório Testes]

PS: You can install an extension in the browser for refreshing the page if it becomes annoying.

Hope this helps someone if the constraints apply.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385553/how-can-i-generate-an-html-report-for-junit-results), [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_junitreports.htm) you can find more on how to generate reports for Junit test results.

Answer (score 0):

junit's javadoc unfortunately says that only failed assertions are recorded (http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc_40/index.html)

so it seems it would not be possible

Answer (score 0):

Can you consider ?

1) download junit source
2) to modify the class org.junit.Assert to do whatever modifications you're looking for