# Coversion of Junit XML Report into HTML form

Tags: junit, soapui

I am using soapui free version to generate the report of test cases,but it is only generating a junit report in XML form, now I want to convert that into an HTML form.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that, but you can simply use XSL transformation ([junitreport option](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html)) 
as suggested by this answer [How can I generate an HTML report for Junit results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385553/how-can-i-generate-an-html-report-for-junit-results)

```
<junitreport todir="${outputdir}">
    <fileset dir="${jrdir}">
        <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
    </fileset>
    <report todir="${outputdir}/html"
        styledir="junitreport"
        format="frames">
        <param name="key1" expression="value1"/>
        <param name="key2" expression="value2"/>
    </report>
</junitreport>
```

I would also suggest to consider the possibility to use TestNG, please find out all details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768214/testng-or-junit-in-java/12768737#12768737

Comment: Please update reference link given for TestNG based solution.