# How to save the test result of Junit with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, junit, selenium-ide

i'm trying to get the result of jUnit test with Eclipse in a separate file as txt file.
What should i add in the java unit code?

I was trying with build.xml but i have the following error :

```
build.xml:100: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/serializer/ExtendedContentHandler
```

I tried to resolve this by adding Junit.jar but still i have the same error.
So that's i want to try to get the result in a file.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In the top right corner of the Junit test runner, you can see a dropdown. Click that and you will find an option to export. Export the test result to the desired location. You will get the XML format of the test report in the provided location.

Answer (score 0):

Generate Ant build file for your project and use Ant to generate junit reports. Refer [this](http://earlwillis.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/getting-started-with-junit-reports/).

Also check this post [How can I generate an HTML report for Junit results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385553/how-can-i-generate-an-html-report-for-junit-results).

Comment: Thank you Chandraya, in the tutorial everything is working except tha transformation from xml to html. I followed what you are refering but i was not able to produce the html file