# How to get Maven report in html format?

Tags: java, maven

i have a maven project with eclipse with some selenium tests.
I can run them in command line and i got the report in my target folder in txt and xml format.

But i want the report in html format.
Whatt should i add in my POM file.

Thank you very much.

Here is my POM.xml

```
....
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>2.44.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
     <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: 1. What does this have to do with eclipse? 2. which of the many Maven reports are you looking for? 3. never ever use the java.net repository.

Comment: I need the basic report result in html format

Comment: There is no such thing that I know of as 'the basic report'. When you run 'mvn site:site', you get a selection of reports depending on what you have in the reporting element of your POM, in HTML.

Comment: I want the Report on the test results of the project in html format , actually i have it in txt and xml format.

Comment: I want something like this              <target name="junitreport">
        <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}Reports"/>
        </junitreport>
    </target> , but this is in Build.xml file for Ant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385553/how-can-i-generate-an-html-report-for-junit-results), as the 2nd answer points out, you should be able to use the Maven [Surefire Report plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/).

*"The Surefire Report Plugin parses the generated TEST-*.xml files under ${basedir}/target/surefire-reports and renders them using DOXIA, which creates the web interface version of the test results."*

Here is the XML to configure it:

```
<reporting>
 <plugins>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18</version>
  </plugin>

 </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Either of the following commands will invoke it:

- `mvn site`
- `mvn surefire-report:report`