# How to log results of JUnit test to a file?

Tags: java, junit

I never used a logging mechanism before, but now I have requirement to log the results of my JUnit tests to a file.

I want to log the result of below test (whether pass, fail or throw exception) to a log file.

```
@Test
public void statusCode200() {
    Assert.assertEquals("Java class".getStatusCode(), 200);
}
```

Can someone please advise how to achieve this?

---

From the comments:

I am currently using this logging mechanism: –  ginny singh 22 mins ago

```
fileHandler = new FileHandler(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//ExecutionResults.log");
simpleFormatter = new SimpleFormatter(); 
StreamHandler sh = new StreamHandler(System.out, simpleFormatter); 
log.setUseParentHandlers(false); 
log.addHandler(sh);   
log.addHandler(fileHandler); 
fileHandler.setFormatter(simpleFormatter); 
fileHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL); 
log.setLevel(Level.ALL); 
log.config("Logger Configuration done."); 
fileHandler.close();
```

Comment: Why would you ever need to do this?

Comment: i am aware that console logs everything But i want to save results for later. Also if you close log, you ended up loosing all that unlike log file

Comment: Why don't you just use a logging framework like Log4j or Logback?

Comment: You can export test report instead. So you will be able to review test results later.

Comment: Firstly, Thanks for replies.

Comment: i am currently using this logging mechanism:

Comment: fileHandler = new FileHandler(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//ExecutionResults.log");
             simpleFormatter = new SimpleFormatter();
            StreamHandler sh = new StreamHandler(System.out, simpleFormatter);
            log.setUseParentHandlers(false);
            log.addHandler(sh);
            log.addHandler(fileHandler);
            fileHandler.setFormatter(simpleFormatter);
            fileHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            log.config("Logger Configuration done.");
            fileHandler.close();

Comment: hope, its easy to read..........

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385553/how-can-i-generate-an-html-report-for-junit-results

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TestWatcher`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) rule from the `JUnit` library

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class LogJunitTests {
    private static StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() throws IOException {
        PrintWriter logFile = new PrintWriter("You Log Path", "UTF-8");
        logFile.write(builder.toString());
        logFile.close();
    }

    @Rule
    public TestWatcher watchman = new TestWatcher() {

        @Override
        protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
            if (description != null) {
                builder.append(description);
            }
            if (e != null) {
                builder.append(' ');
                builder.append(e);
            }
            builder.append(" FAIL\n");
        }

        @Override
        protected void succeeded(Description description) {
            if (description != null) {
                builder.append(description);
            }
            builder.append(" OK\n");
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertEquals("Java class", "Java class");
    }
}
```