# Generate static HTML results report with Python Behave

Tags: python, python-behave

I use behave to run a set of e2e tests for my software, eg:

```
behave ./tests/ --tags=set123 --tags=-skip
```

When the process ends, a `tests/results/` directory is created, plenty of results in the form of `.xml` files which root element is `<testsuite>`.

I'd like to have an *static* HTML report with the result. PyCharm have a nice button to get such report directly, but I wonder about how to get it from the command line. I mean, some way of processing the resulting `.xml` files to render the HTML or (even better) to do it as result of the `behave` command itself.

Any help, please? This seems to be conceptually easy but I haven't found any straighfoward solution googling out there...

**EDIT:** I know the [Allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/) tool. However, it doesn't fit my purpose as it starts a web server to serve the report and I need an static HTML. I have adjusted the wording of the question to make it clearer.

Comment: check out this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45012628/650884

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Pavel! I'm trying to follow it, but it seems that the allure APT installation described at https://docs.qameta.io/allure/latest/ is for Ubuntu... trying to hack to make it work with Debian fail in packages dependencies. Keep trying...

Comment: I finally managed to run allure. However, the problem is that this tools starts a web server to server the pages. I need an static HTML solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @fgalan - did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue as you nowadays.

Comment: @Helping Hands, I'm afraid I didn't so far :(

Comment: @fgalan - No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you don t have a lot of tests you can think on change framework to pytest + pytest_bdd and then you can generate html static reports with pytest-html. Or even , i don t know if possible , call pytest report from behave