# How to Allure-behave generate report from test cases. Allure generated only one report from one test case

Tags: allure, python-behave

When I use this step from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763066/how-to-generate-reports-in-behave-python/45012628) twice:

```
$ behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o %allure_result_folder% ./features
```

And then

```
$ allure serve %allure_result_folder%
```

There is always 1 test case. How can I manage to sum test cases? 
I want to see test cases.

I've run also this code twice:

```
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o results ./features
```

and then:

```
allure generate results/ -o report/
```

But still, I get only 1 test case.

I want to see for example
[similar outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsbCL.png)

Comment: All things above is ok, looks like a bug or some anything. We need more info about your features and behave/allure version. Can you provide it via gitter or as new issue on official  repo?

Answer (score 6):

I have a couple guesses at what's going on wrong.

First you said you've run the same thing twice which makes me think you may have an incorrect assumption on how Allure seems to organize results. If you've only written 1 Behave scenario, running the same test twice will only show 1 test. If you click on the test subsequent runs show up under the "Retries" tab (Not sure why it isn't called history but if you need History it's now at bottom of answer). You'll need 2 behave scenarios for a second test to appear.

[image]

Second, you're results folder seems to be changing paths you mention both `report`, `results` and `%allure_result_folder%`. Make sure you create a results folder before running behave and have the same path for `-o` in the behave command and after `allure serve`. So for example if you have a folder structure like so:

`folder_you_are_in/
├── features/
│   ├── steps/
├── allure/
│   ├── results/
|   ├── reports/`

You want to run the command like so:

```
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o allure/results ./features
```

Then the path you need to `allure generate` & `allure open` (not `allure serve`, not sure why but serve doesn't seem to take history into account when it generates as part of command) and make sure your paths match your file structure:

```
allure generate allure/results/ -o allure/reports
allure open allure/reports
```

The screenshot seems to show just a test with multiple Feature files and scenarios. But if you're looking for how to make History Work you need to move the history file from previous report into the results file for new report for some reason this is only done automatically with the build plugins and must be run [manually](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/682) when testing locally. So something like this:

First test run

```
 behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o allure/results ./features
```

Generate report for first test run

```
 allure generate allure/results/ -o allure/reports
```

Second Test Run

```
 behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o allure/results ./features
```

Copy the History Folder from the Report Generated at Step 2 to The Results from Step 3

```
 cp -R allure/reports/history allure/results/history
```

Generate the 2nd Allure Report

```
 allure generate allure/results/ -o allure/reports --clean
```

And open it with

```
 allure open allure/reports
```

Comment: This seems a very helpful answer. I do have one question though, It opens the report properly when I open it by given allure open command. But if I click on index.html and open in browser, it says loading always. can you please give me any idea on that?

Comment: None of the data loads, in chrome console it explains it, `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/blah/blah/blah/allure-reports/widgets/summary.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.` There's something in CORS policy's to browsers that block loading data from local files. Not sure how `allure open` gets around it, you'd have to look at the code. Hope that helps.

Comment: They run it on a jetty server so it doesn't run into CORS errors.