# How to Create Html report in android studio using Junit

Tags: junit, automation, appium-android, html-reports-jenkins

i don't have any idea about how to create Html report in android studio using Junit. please tell me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate an HTML report for Junit results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385553/how-can-i-generate-an-html-report-for-junit-results)