# Junit testing assert output not being displayed on console

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, groovy, junit

I am trying to implement Junit test using Spring boot I have written some simple test when I am running the ApplicationTests.groovy as junit test it showing green color bar when the test is successful and red upon errors but it is not displaying any output I am getting empty stack trace upon successful test methods though I am using `assert`.

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration
import org.junit.Assert.*;
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application)
@WebAppConfiguration
class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void testAssertions() {
        assertTrue(1 == 1)
        assertEquals("test", "test")

        def x = "42"
        assertNotNull "x must not be null", x
        assertNull null

        assertSame x, x
    }
  }
```

Comment: Similar question is already answered here... Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180398/can-i-make-junit-more-verbose

Comment: @uthavaakkarai - I am doing same exact thing what he has suggested but still same issue ?